# What are options for power button

Tags: settings

I have Moto E (2nd Generation Android version 5.0.2) .I use power ON/OFF button to lock the smartphone phone or to go into the sleep mode.
Due to frequent use of power ON button, the switch is not working properly.It needs to press it long and hard.

So are there other options available except power button

1.To lock the smartphone

2.To make smartphone go into sleep mode.
and

3.To turn ON the smartphone.

Comment: IDK about 1. but 2. can be achieved easily by "Gravitybox" (your OS should meet it's requirements; root required) and 3. can be achieved by  a custom kernel that supports double-tap to wake up. Please [edit] your question and mention the Android version you're using; are you willing to root the device?

Comment: @Firelord I have edited question. Due to frequent use,I had to replace the switch of the power button. that's why I want other keys or shortcuts which can do the work of power button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apps like.   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enlace.doubletap

For sleep or wake this app works pretty well but I don't suppose if it's ever possible to power on the phone with an app installed in it and phone is switched OFF.